# Python interpreter problem in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I installed python 3.11 from microsoft store, instaled visual studio code and python extension. But when I try to run "hello world" vsc says that "python is not installed" and shows warning: Identifier for virt-virtualenv failed to identify. When I manually select enter path to python 3.11 it doesn't work and system shows this: "system cannot get access to this file".

I tried reinstalling everything and installing in different ways, from different sources and nothing helps.

I again tried installing python (this time once againt from python.org), and this time I can select interpreter, but when I try to run python file I get this:
PS C:\Users\Łukasz> & C:/Users/Łukasz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe Untitled-1
C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Łukasz\Untitled-1': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Łukasz>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To the left of visual studio code, check for the recommended extensions and install them
2. Open terminal and confirm that you have python install using the command `python --version`
3. Check the bottom right of your vscode and see what language it is shown (it should be showing python)
4. Maybe the problem is with the virtual environment you selected (or that was automatically assigned).

Comment: ad 1 - I did. I installed Python extension from Microsoft. Ad. 2 I confirmed, it works. 3. It shows "Select interpreter' ad. 4 I have this problem without interfering in any settings.

Comment: @Łukasz so you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, but I again tried installing python (this time once againt from python.org), and this time I can select interpreter, but when I try to run python file I get this: PS C:\Users\Łukasz> & C:/Users/Łukasz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe Untitled-1 C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Łukasz\Untitled-1': [Errno 2] No such file or directory PS C:\Users\Łukasz>

Comment: I tried reinstalling everything for one more time (I think it was more than 20 times that I tried it since yesterday) and now it works. I don't know why, because I did everything the same...

Comment: Ahah, sometimes it can be like that

Answer (score 0):

if VS Code doesn't work, try installing IDLE from python.org. If you want to use vs code, use select interpreter and select (one of) the options. To do select interpreter, click on the search bar thing near the top(image attached) and click on show and run commands and then select interpreter [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdNnn.png.)

Comment: "try installing IDLE from python.org" - I tried, same thing. "Use select interpreter" - it shows "python is not installed" (it is installed), when I manualy enter the path it doesn't work and system shows this: "system cannot get access to this file":(

Comment: I tried reinstalling everything for one more time (I think it was more than 20 times that I tried it since yesterday) and now it works. I don't know why, because I did everything the same...

Answer (score 0):

try using brew install python if you have homebrew, otherwise run /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
then brew install python. https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).